# Percentage chance of bringing home a raffle prize

Tags: percentages

So I bought 3 tickets for a raffle and 100 tickets were sold. Once tickets are taken out they are not returned to the pot to win again. There are 40 prizes total. What are the odds that I win 1 prize out of the 40 and what are the odds that all 3 of my tickets are winners?

Comment: What have you tried?  If you had just one ticket, what is the chance it wins something?

Comment: If I had just one ticket it would be 40/100= 40% but I don’t know how to calculate for having more than one ticket